# Pagination and htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, pagination

I am looking for some help in my htaccess to better handle my urls when using a pagination function.

Currently my htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    index.php?alias=$1    [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    index.php?alias=$1/$2    [QSA,NC,L]
```

basically, I have two rules.  At first I only had the second one, to direct all requests to my index page, where I then parse out some details of the url in order to show the correct content.  I found that it didnt work for urls with only one sub directory, like example.com/bars, but only two directories like, example.com/bars/bar-name, so I added the rule before it.

This has been working great for me.  All of my urls look great and the ?alias=bars/bars-name has been completlely hidden and now looks like /bars/bars-name

Recently though I have integrated a pagination php function.  This function creates urls that looks like this:

```
example.com/bars?alias=bars&info=mysql_table_bars&page=2
```

Basically, 'info' is the table name that the pagination function queries, and 'page' is the current page.  It seems 'alias' also started showing in the url once I started using this function.

What I would like is for my pagination to look like these examples:

```
example.com/bars/page/2
example.com/hotels/page/5
etc...
```

What do I need to add to my htaccess to handle this situation?  Also, is there a way to simplify my existing two rules?

Comment: Erm why you are showing the table name in url? Just curious.

Comment: I guess it is a requirement of the pagination function so it knows what data it is working with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your original rules. The conditions that you have only get applied to the immediately following `RewriteRule`, so you need to duplicate them:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    index.php?alias=$1    [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    index.php?alias=$1/$2    [QSA,NC,L]
```

For the new pagination stuff, firstly, *it is really bad to be pulling database table names from the query string*, unless they've been validated somehow (which may be what's happening). But even then, it's still an information disclosure problem. So you can use these rules to always remove them:

```
# This matches the actual request when there's pagination in the query string
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/\?]+)\?alias=([^&\ ]+)&info=.*&page=([0-9]+)

# an optional sanity check, does the request URI match the "alias" param?
RewriteCond %1:%2:%3 ^(.*):\1:(.*)$

# redirect the browser to the URL with the table name removed
RewriteRule ^ /%1/page/%2? [L,R=301]
```

Then you need rules to internally rewrite them back to the request with the query string:

```
# rewrite it back to the query string
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/page/([0-9]+) /$1?alias=$1&info=mysql_table_$1&page=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm noticing a few issues though.  So if I am looking at a page of results and scroll to the pagination, and click any page number, it correctly takes me to /page/2 or page/5 and does indeed show the correct page.  The correct page of results isnt set in the pagination though, so I'm guessing that ?page=5 is needed for that to be updated.  I was assuming it would still be passed silently somehow.

Comment: $_GET['page'] does indeed seem to be set, so I am going thru my paginate function to see what the issue might be

Comment: I was able to solve my issue.  While I was poking around in there I also took the table name out of the url and instead passed it as a variable.  Thanks again for your help!